# Cannot append two consecutive list elements after comparing with second list using Python

Tags: python

I have a list with 35 elements as titles called ch_titles.
I web scrape a page and I get from a ul, titles and values which are variable in number.

For Example:

```
ch_titles=['RAM','CPU Model','Graphics','RAM Type','Hard Disk','Resolution']

Edited_MyListValues=['RAM','16GB','Graphics','NVidia']
```

I am trying to get as final result:

```
Edited_MyListValues=['RAM','16GB','Graphics','NVidia','CPU Model','N/A','RAM Type','N/A','Hard Disk','N/A','Resolution','N/A']
```

**My goal is to have a list 70 elements (titles and values)**

So I try the following to check if element in titles exist in result list and if not add it with append and add a default value again with append.

```
for i in ch_titles:
    Words = i.split(" ")
    LastWord = Words[-1]
    CountWords = len(i.split(" ")) 
    FirstLetter = LastWord[0]
    if FirstLetter.isupper:
        FirtLetterLow = FirstLetter.lower()
        FirstLetterUp = FirstLetter
    else:
        FirtLetterLow = FirstLetter
        FirstLetterUp = FirstLetter.upper()

    if i.startswith(FirstLetterUp) or i.startswith(FirtLetterLow):
        if i not in Edited_MyListValues:
            Edited_MyListValues.append(i)
            Edited_MyListValues.append('N/A')
            print(Edited_MyListValues)
```

I notice that even if I can add the missing title in the end an additional value is not added

Comment: You can make this code a little simpler by removing the `if...else` block and having your second condition be `if i.lower().startswith(FirstLetter):`. Aside from that, I'm not too sure what you're trying to accomplish here. A little more detail, as well as some example input/output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What if you iterated through the first list and reshaped the second?**

```
ch_titles=['RAM','CPU Model','Graphics','RAM Type','Hard Disk','Resolution']

Edited_MyListValues = ['RAM','16GB','Graphics','NVidia']

# convert to a dictionary
Edited_MyListValues_dict = dict(zip(Edited_MyListValues[::2], Edited_MyListValues[1::2]))

# iterate through titles
for title in ch_titles:
    if title not in Edited_MyListValues_dict.keys():
        # set value to nan if values are not in keys
        Edited_MyListValues_dict[title] = np.nan

# convert to a flat list (if you so desire it)
Edited_MyListValues = [item for pair in Edited_MyListValues_dict.items() for item in pair]
```

Comment: what is np I need to import numpy??

Comment: Yes @MariaGeorgali Alternatively, you can write `None` which would have a similar desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks very overcomplicated for the thing you want to achieve.

Simple loop with one if would do the same output you want to get:

(Plus avoid naming your variables with upper letter. You can check [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for naming conventions)

```py
Edited_MyListValues_lower = [i.lower() for i in Edited_MyListValues]
for i in ch_titles:
    if i.lower() not in Edited_MyListValues_lower:
        Edited_MyListValues.extend((i, 'N/A'))
```

Answer (score 2):

So I am just assuming all values that are in Edited_MyListValues are validated?  If so:

```
Edited_MyListValues_lower = [val.lower() for val in Edited_MyListValues]
ch_unused_titles= [val for val in ch_titles if val.lower() not in Edited_MyListValues_lower]

for title in ch_unused_titles:
   Edited_MyListValues.extend((title, 'N/A'))
```